# kubectl port-forward multiple services

Tags: macos, kubectl, portforwarding

I have been trying to forward multiple ports with these commands:

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/service1 8080:8080 && kubectl port-forward deployment/service2 8081:8081
```

and

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/service1 8080:8080 || kubectl port-forward deployment/service2 8081:8081
```

it seems like it's only forwarding the first one with this output:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
```

how can I make it to listen in the background and run the second command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After the shell runs the first [`kubectl port-foward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward) command, the process blocks and the second command would only ever begin after the first terminates (which it likely won't).

To `kubectl port-forward` for multiple services, you would need to put each command into the background:

```bash
kubectl port-forward deployment/service1 8080:8080 & \
kubectl port-forward deployment/service2 8081:8081 &
```

> **NOTE** `&` is the bash instruction to run the command in the background (in a subshell). I've used `\` to pretty-print the command on multiple lines but you can write multiple commands (separated by `&`) on a single line, e.g.
>
> ```bash
> echo "First" & echo "Second" & echo "Third" &
> ```

Comment: great! it's really working!
but can we do it from another aliases? let's say `alias srv1="kubectl port-forward deployment/service1 8080:8080"`, and `alias srv2="kubectl port-forward deployment/service2 8081:8081"`, alias forward-x="srv1 & srv2", when I tried to run `forward-x` it's still only forward the first one. but when I typed the full commands, it works perfectly.

Comment: is it possible to reconnect if port-forwarding to one of the services is stopped?

Answer (score 9):

Here are my two cents with a shell script example:

```bash
# Push commands in the background, when the script exits, the commands will exit too
kubectl --context "$SELECTED_CONTEXT" --namespace "$SELECTED_NS" port-forward service/service1 1433:1433 & \
kubectl --context "$SELECTED_CONTEXT" --namespace "$SELECTED_NS" port-forward service/service2 80:80 & \

echo "Press CTRL-C to stop port forwarding and exit the script"
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the service to forward the ports
Assume you're using helm to make a new release.

In this case we'll be forwarding two services to our local environment:

- MinIO
- PostgresSQL

```js
helm upgrade --install -f values-file.yaml <release-name> /path/to/helm/templates/ -n <namespace> --create-namespace

kubectl -- --namespace <namespace> port-forward service/<release-name>-minio 9000 & \

kubectl -- --namespace <namespace> port-forward service/<release-name> 5432
```