# Powershell - execute multiple commands - kubectl port-forward on Windows

Tags: powershell, kubectl, portforwarding

I'm running minikube (no tunnel) on Windows 10

Is it possible to run multiple commands that block the console until exited all at once?  I am looking at `kubectl port-forward` here.

```
kubectl port-forward -n istio-system service/grafana 13000:3000;
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/web-ui-deployment-ff6ffbd44-5vxqk 8080:1337;
```

Only outputs:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:13000 -> 3000
Forwarding from [::1]:13000 -> 3000
```

Essentially it is blocking the next one from running.  Ctrl+C just stops all from running.

This one is for mac - [kubectl port-forward multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980275/kubectl-port-forward-multiple-services).

The commands can run individually in two PowerShell terminals so I don't think the issue lies with commands being hung.

**NOTE:** Running one command requires a Ctrl+C to exit it.

Comment: How do you know that the first command is "blocking" the next one? Perhaps the second one is just hung...

Comment: I've updated question.  The commands run fine if executed in two different terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command will "block" in terms that once launched, PowerShell will wait until the process finishes (e.g. till you hit Ctrl + C to end task) before it will return and run the next command. Like the example that you linked to, the solution is to launch the process in the background, which allows the next command to run. You can do this with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

```
Start-Process kubectl -ArgumentList "port-forward -n istio-system service/grafana 13000:3000"
Start-Process kubectl -ArgumentList "port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/web-ui-deployment-ff6ffbd44-5vxqk 8080:1337"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can start two background jobs with `Start-Job`:

```
$jobs = @(
  Start-Job {kubectl port-forward -n istio-system service/grafana 13000:3000}
  Start-Job {kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/web-ui-deployment-ff6ffbd44-5vxqk 8080:1337}
) 

try {
  Write-Host "Port forwarding jobs running. Press Ctrl+C to stop..."
  $jobs |Wait-Job
}
finally {
  $jobs |Remove-Job -Force
}
```

To kill it, simply press Ctrl+C to interrupt `Wait-Job`, causing the `finally` block to execute

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the erroneous "}".  It can be tricky to stop with Ctrl+C - seems a little unresponsive - but it does work.